# Getting Number of Common Values from 2 comma-seperated strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains comma-separated values in a column In Postgres.

```
ID                          PRODS
--------------------------------------
1                           ,142,10,75,
2                           ,142,87,63,
3                           ,75,73,2,58,
4                           ,142,2,
```

Now I want a query where I can give a comma-separated string and it will tell me the number of matches between the input string and the string present in the row.

For instance, for input value `',142,87,'`, I want the output like

```
ID                          PRODS                        No. of Match
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                           ,142,10,75,                  1
2                           ,142,87,63,                  2
3                           ,75,73,2,58,                 0
4                           ,142,2,                      1
```

Comment: what are you matching with what ....your question is not at all clear

Comment: This is awful database design.  We could cope with searching for a single value in a CSV string, but CSV on both ends is bufugly.  You should normalize your data.

Comment: You are right Tim, This is quite old data structure. but as of now, I have to live with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.

```
    select T.*,
    COALESCE(No_of_Match,'0')  
    from TT T Left join
    (
        select ID,count(ID) No_of_Match 
        from (
                select ID,unnest(string_to_array(trim(t.prods, ','), ',')) A
                from TT t)a 
        Where A in ('142','87')
        group by ID
    )B
    On T.Id=b.id
```

[Demo Here](http://rextester.com/KGFTQ86297)

> OutPut

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ARRAY(
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            unnest(string_to_array(trim(both ',' from prods), ',')) 
        WHERE 
            unnest = ANY(string_to_array(',142,87,', ','))
    )
FROM
    prods_table;
```

Output is:

```
1   ,142,10,75,     {142}
2   ,142,87,63,     {142,87}
3   ,75,73,2,58,    {}
4   ,142,2,         {142}
```

Add the [`cardinality(anyarray)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) function to the last column to get just a number of matches.

And consider changing your database design.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the intarray extension, this gets quite easy:

```
select id, prods, cardinality(string_to_array(trim(prods, ','), ',')::int[] & array[142,87])
from bad_design;
```

Otherwise it's a bit more complicated:

```
select bd.id, bd.prods, m.matches
from bad_design bd
  join lateral (
    select bd.id, count(v.p) as matches
    from unnest(string_to_array(trim(bd.prods, ','), ',')) as l(p)
      left join ( 
         values ('142'),('87')  --<< these are your input values
      ) v(p) on l.p = v.p
    group by bd.id
  ) m on m.id = bd.id
order by bd.id;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZIYS97736

But you should **really** fix your data model.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as
( 
select *, 
unnest(string_to_array(trim(both ',' from prods), ',') ) as v
from myTable
),
counts as 
(
select id, count(t) as c from data 
left join 
( select unnest(string_to_array(',142,87,', ',') ) as t) tmp on tmp.t = data.v 
group by id
order by id
)
select t1.id, t1.prods, t2.c as "No. of Match"
from myTable t1
inner join counts t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```